# How do I set the default menu item in a ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

In my application I am using a popup menu item when right clicking an object. I dynamically build up this menu using code like this:

```
ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item1", aNiceImage, someFunction));
menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item2", alsoNiceImage, someOtherFunction));
```

Now I want to set one of these menu items in bold (as it is recommended by the Windows User Experience Guidelines) to indicate which action corresponds with double clicking the object.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use `item.Font = new Font(item.Font, item.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold)` to make bold effect to the current font.

you can also auto select the default item as follows:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
  contextMenuStrip1.Items[3].Select();
}
```

Comment: This works for me in WPF project `ToolStripMenuItem1.Font = new Font(ToolStripMenuItem1.Font, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.font.aspx) property to specify a font with the desired [`FontStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx):

```
myToolStripMenuItem.Font = new Font(
    FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,
    12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Obviously altering the inputs for the desired output, `FontStyle.Bold` being the important part here.